# Custom Posttype and menu classes

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I'm working on a custom theme for a website, and this website has a custom posttype 'Recipes'.

I added custom menu support and made a menu item which points to www.websitename.com/recipes
And everything works fine.

But now I have the following problem with the 'active' classes for the menu. When you're on the custom posttype archive page of single page. The 'default' blog page gets the active class (current_page_parent)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Add Custom Post Types Achives to Nav Menus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-custom-post-types-archive-to-nav-menus/) plugin?  I just tested this locally and I get a `current-menu-item` class on both the archive page and also on the single post type.

Comment: Yeah I tried that plugin, but it doesn't fix the problem. I do indeed get `current-menu-item` on the archive page. But at the same time, the blog page gets `current_page_parent`

Comment: Fair point. I think I read your question too quickly.

Comment: Well, could also be it's not to well formulated ;) But thanks nonetheless.